# how to create jackson based json rest service with Spring 2

Tags: json, rest, jackson, spring2.x

Spring 3 has native json support for returning json response using @ResponseBody spring 3 annotation.

My app is based on spring 2 and need to create jackson based rest service which will return json when client make http rest request using browser.

I am exploring how to achieve this. Any body suggestions on this is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spring 3 we have default converter which converts any object (using Jackson) to JSON. We can override this default converter to define some specials settings. In Spring 2 we can implement [View](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/2.5.1/org/springframework/web/servlet/View.java#View). You can implement this view using Jackson library to convert any object to JSON.

Your controller could look like that:

```
public ModelAndView generateJson(.....) {
     //business logic

     return new ModelAndView(new JsonView(objectToConvert);
}
```